Installing Nebular 13 in Angular 17
I was asked to make an admin dashboard using angular and nebular UI components, but it seems that the documentation of nebular is out of date.
I tried 2 approaches:

to install it using ng add @nebular/theme, but I get this error: Could not read Angular module file: /src/null.ts

to install it manually by using the following commands:
npm install --save @nebular/theme @angular/cdk @angular/animations
npm install --save eva-icons @nebular/eva-icons
npm install --save @nebular/auth @nebular/security



The second approach when I tried, at first made me think that I installed it successfully, but when I tried to import modules in my standalone app component, and then tried to use the nb card component, it didn't have any styles, as If I wrote some text on the html file without including a CSS file, I searched for a solution to this problem and I found out that I should wrap everything in my app.component.html in nb-layout and nb-layout-column but I got some errors like:
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_NbMediaBreakpointsService   -> _NbMediaBreakpointsService -> _NbMediaBreakpointsService]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for _NbMediaBreakpointsService!

That is the app.component.ts file:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import {
  NB_MEDIA_BREAKPOINTS,
  NB_THEME_OPTIONS,
  NbCardModule,
  NbLayoutModule,
  NbStatusService,
  NbThemeModule,
  NbThemeOptions,
  NbThemeService,
} from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, NbCardModule, NbThemeModule, NbLayoutModule],
  providers: [
    NbStatusService,
    NbThemeService,
    { provide: NB_THEME_OPTIONS, useValue: {} as NbThemeOptions },
    { provide: NB_MEDIA_BREAKPOINTS, useValue: {} as any },
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent {}

This is the app.component.html file:
<nb-layout>
  <nb-layout-column>
    <nb-card>
      <nb-card-header>Card Header</nb-card-header>
      <nb-card-body> This is the body of the card. </nb-card-body>
      <nb-card-footer>Card Footer</nb-card-footer>
    </nb-card>
  </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>

I even tried to download the ngx-admin project from github but, after running the command npm i, I got more errors and the installation failed.
When making the project I chose the CSS stylesheet format and chose to not have server-side rendering, I don't know if this information is relevant or not, but I wanted to say everything I remember in my problem.

Welcome to SO. Have you seen this possible solution?

please help me, I can't find the solution in the link you sent, I visited that link before but I didn't know that it contained the solution, I saw multiple users say that they have the same issue
